# Program that does not return anything

Tags: c

I am working on a program in C that can return loan payment.
yearInt is year interest
loanAmt is total amount of loan
monthlyPay is monthly payment
numberPay is number of monthly payment

For some reasons, when I run the program, there is nothing shows up, even I type in a negative number.

Is there anyway to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
float yearInt = -1;
int loanAmt = -1;
float monthlyPay = -1;
int numberPay = -1;
int count = 0;

while (loanAmt<0)
{
    printf("Please enter valid loan value: \n");
    scanf("%f", &loanAmt);
}

while (yearInt<0)
{
    printf("Please enter valid yearly interest value: \n");
    scanf("%f", &yearInt)
}

while (monthlyPay<0)
{
    printf("Please enter valid monthly payment value: \n");
    scanf("%f", &monthlyPay);
}

while (numberPay<0)
{
    printf("Please enter valid number of monthly payments: \n");
    scanf("%f", &numberPay);
}

if(loanAmt>monthlyPay)
{
    while(count<numberPay)
    {
        loanAmt = loanAmt*(1 + (yearInt/12)) - monthlyPay;
        count += count+1;
    }
    printf("The amount of last payment is: %.2f\n", loanAmt);
else
    printf("The amount of last payment is: %.2f\n", loanAmt);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Variable loanAmt is declared as having type int but in the loop you are using format specifier %f. At least change it to %d.   while (loanAmt<0)
{
    printf("Please enter valid loan value: \n");
    scanf("%f", &loanAmt);
}

Comment: Please edit your post and include the _real_ code which compiles (copy/paste it). And also indent it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 scanf("%f", &loanAmt);         // loanAmt is int
 ... 
 scanf("%f", &numberPay);       //numberPay is int
```

In both wrong argument is passed to `%f` , therefore , causes UB . Use `%d` specifier .

And in this one `}` is missing -

```
if(loanAmt>monthlyPay)
{
   while(count<numberPay)
   {
     loanAmt = loanAmt*(1 + (yearInt/12)) - monthlyPay;
     count += count+1;
   }
   printf("The amount of last payment is: %.2f\n", loanAmt);    //use %d 
     // ADD '}' here 
else    // ADD '{' here 
   printf("The amount of last payment is: %.2f\n", loanAmt);    //use %d 
}
```

Put a `}` before `else {`.

Comment: Thank you!  If I use %d can I still keep 2 decimal place?

Comment: @XinLi integers can't be( _more precisely they don't have_) represented with decimal place . If you want answer with decimals you should declare that variables as `float ` or `double`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong format specifier to read `loanAmount` and `numberPay`. Instead of `"%f"`, use `"%d"`.

```
scanf("%d", &loanAmt);
```

and

```
scanf("%d", &numberPay);
```

Also, always check the return value of `scanf` to make sure that it was able to assign data to all the variables.

Change the loop:

```
while (loanAmt<0)
{
   printf("Please enter valid loan value: \n");
   scanf("%d", &loanAmt);
}
```

to

```
while (loanAmt<0)
{
   printf("Please enter valid loan value: \n");
   if ( scanf("%d", &loanAmt) != 1 )
   {
      // Discard the rest of the line.
      int c;
      while ( (c = fgetc(stdin)) = '\n' && c != EOF );
   }
}
```

It will be still better to put all the checks in a function and call the function from `main`.

```
int readInt(char const* prompt)
{
   int val = -1;

   printf("%s\n", prompt);
   while ( scanf("%f", &val) != 1 || val < 0)
   {
      // Discard rest of the line.
      int c;
      while ( (c = fgetc(stdin)) = '\n' && c != EOF );

      // If EOF is reached, we have a problem.
      if ( c == EOF )
      {
         exit(0);
      }
      printf("%s\n", prompt);
   }

   return val;
}
```

and then, use:

```
loanAmount = readInt("Please enter valid loan value: ");
```

Add a similar function to read `float`s and call it for reading the variables that are of type `float`.

Comment: Thanks a lot to fix it. After fixing this, when I compile it, it says "syntax error before "else" ". Do you know what is going on?

Comment: @XinLi missing brace from the `if` block.

Comment: Suggest using the return value of `scanf()` to determine loop continuation rather than `val < 0` - else how does `readInt()` return negative numbers?  Corner case fail: Unless `scanf("%d", &val)` returns 1, do not trust the contents of `val`.  In theory, `scanf()` can return `EOF` to signify input error, in which case, `val` is undefined.

Comment: @chux, All valid points except the one about negative numbers. The OP's requirement seems to be that the number cannot be a negative number. Updated the answer.

Comment: Agree OP's requirement implies non-negative numbers.  Function name `readInt()` does not carry that same connotation.  IAC - a small matter.

Comment: @chux. IAC?? A new acronym for me.

Comment: IAC: In any case _or_ should you agree or disagree, the following applies